# Traditional DOM Manipulation Angular 2/Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, angular

I am trying to add a google maps places autocomplete search input to an angular 2 application, I am trying to figure out how to proceed with it.  So far I have a component, and OnInit i am trying to run the necessary google code.  Google's code is simple Javascript like:

`var input = document.getElementById('pace-input')
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options)`

I assume I have to use ElementRef to grab the DOM elements and run this code, but I can't wrap my head around how to do that.  Can anyone help me with traditional DOM manipulation with Angular 2, or suggest a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  Used `@ViewChild('pacinput') ref: ElementRef;`

To grab the element then afterViewOnInit:

> `let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((this.ref.nativeElement),{types: ['geocode']});`

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing in angular 2.  However, I've run into a different error.  I'm getting  angular2-polyfills.js:142 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zone' of null  when I reference <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[mykey]&libraries=places"></script>

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution to your problem. But it may help you towards right direction.

To manipulate DOM with Angular2, you may use `BrowserDomAdapter` api.

[Right way to use BrowserDomAdapter - Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8XyXgbfcpZcgAq52XeDT?p=preview)

```
import {BrowserDomAdapter} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
export class AppComponent {
 dom:BrowserDomAdapter;
  constructor() { 
    this.dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();
  }
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it a bit different. This is an example with autocompletion of cities. First I implement AfterViewInit and in the ngAfterView method I call the google.api:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      var autocompleteElm = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('autocomplete');
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      (autocompleteElm), {
        types: ['(cities)']
      });
    }
```

If anyone is interested I load the google api in my index.html file and create a dummy reference in my Component class file outside the class:

```
declare var google: any;
```